Forgotten Title "Poison Master From Wuxia" Story

This novel is most likely a Western fan creation, not Korean, Japanese or Chinese.
Poison master reincarnates from a wuxia world into a world where monsters exist and pose a threat to humanity.
This poison master enters the body of a despised young master. His stepmother is trying to assassinate him.
MC kills the other soldiers who are trying to kill him, and he escapes to another town.
MC discovers that selling/creating medicine through poison could be profitable, and soon his "medicine's" effectiveness spreads to the army. One of his medicines prevents monster mosquitos from slowly sapping the user's stamina, and there are many other effects. His stepmother soon learns of his newfound fame, and plots to assassinate him again from there.


+1 Hi Joka Keekian KK: Did you mean "Western fan" by not Korean, Japanese, or Chinese? Also: "jap" is considered an anti-Japanese slur in the US, so I would avoid using that and just say "Japanese" here.

my bad, but yeah.

"This novel origin is most likely a Western fan creation" so you're thinking that the fan component is that the "despised young master"'s soul has been replaced by the Poison Master? What part is from the original work and what has the fanfic creator added?

if i recall correctly, the entire thing is a fan creation. Like some novels on royalroad, or webnovel
